# Validate each element of a two element array with a different schema

Tags: python, jsonschema

How can I validate each element of the following array using different jsonschema in python?

The array:

```
[22, 33]
```

The validations:

For the first element: `{"type": "number", "minimum": 20, "maximum":23}`

For the second element: `{"type": "number", "minimum": 30, "maximum":35}`

---

So far I have tried using `prefixItems` as specified [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html) without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using `items` as an array:

```
schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 20,
            "maximum": 23,
        },
        {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 30,
            "maximum": 35,
        },
    ],
    "additionalItems": False, # Disallow any other elements
}
```

Finally validate with:

```
jsonschema.validate([22, 33], schema)
```

Comment: It depends on what version of JSON Schema you are using. "items" with array values is only valid in drafts 2019-09 and earlier; in draft2020-12 the array usage was renamed to "prefixItems", and the value under "items" must be a schema (which is applied to all of the array items in the data).